# Expressing past tense of PAIN

Tags: past-tense, expressions

Please correct me if am wrong,

What is the appropriate way of expressing the past tense of **pain**

Should it be, "I am pained" or "I was pained"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The past tense of *pain* is *pained*,  as in "it pained me".

What you are talking about is the passive:

> present, *I am pained by your disrespectful behaviour*, or

> past, *I was pained by your disrespectful behaviour*.

I think it is probably more common to use *pained* adjectivally:

> present: *I am pained to see you behave that way*.

> past: *I was pained to see you behave that way*.